# How should I store Unicode file paths in MySQL and on FTP?

Tags: java, url, encoding, utf-8

I have written a web application where users from all over the world can upload files. These may different character encodings. For that reason I have defined my MySQL database in UTF-8, so it renders all special chars correctly.

However, when a user tries to access a file, the web browser says that it cannot be found, with a weird encoded result. I have tried some different encoding approaches (such as URLEncoder/Decoder), but there are still some use-cases where they don't work.

I want to know how Dropbox, Google, etc. solve this encoding problem.

- Do they save the string in a form like `test+test%C3%BC.txt`?
- Do they rename the file and store it with a secure name (like `123890123.file`)?
- Do they use some other technique?

I am also wondering whether the URLEncoder is the best approach to get things working. For example, it replaces a space with a `+`, instead of with `%20` — why does it do that if no browser can handle a plus for a space?

I need to keep the base URL the same, and encode only the filename.

For example,

```
www.example.com/folder/blä äh.txt
```

should be encoded as

```
www.example.com/folder/bl%..+%...txt
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Side note: `URLEncoder` is to be used only for url parameters (formally for ` application/x-www-form-urlencoded ` data), not path sections. If you use the `URLEncoder` for path sections, you have to work around the `+` vs `%20` issue by postprocessing the result (i.e. `.replace('+','%20')` )

Comment: thanks, I have tried this, but in several times URLEncoder with postprocessing works with "UTF-8" e ncoding, and on other files it fails, but works with "Windows-1215" encoding... I haven't found a uinique way to make all files available (because they are stored with special chars on ftp)...

Comment: That the files are uploaded via FTP (i.e. independent of your web application) is an important information. You might want to mention this in your question. I have a hunch that the encoding problem is not with the database but the files on the file system. The trouble is that java uses the "default encoding" to read file names, and will be at loss if the file names are in an incompatible encoding.

Comment: Hi, yes indeed, the DB works fine. but when I read out the filenames from the db and encode it to be url-safe, it tells me "file not found". even If I go to the ftp directory, I cannot even download the file because the filename is terribly corrupted...